# NavigationDrawer in every Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I created NavigationDrawer for my HomeScreen and now want to add it in every Activity. How can I do this without copy/pasting code into every Activity? Below is my HomeScreen XML code.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_screen_image"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/purple_200"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    MY OTHER CODE

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution in using MaterialDrawer by mikepenz

Answer (score 2):

Normally, IMHO, NavigationDrawer is intended to use with Fragment. A main Activity has its NavigationDrawer that is common among Fragments. So that each Fragment doesn't have to have or manage its own NavigationDrawer.

In Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.navigation_item_1:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment1()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_item_2:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment2()).commit();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

An example of layout/main_activity.xml:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view
     using match_parent for both width and height
     to consume the full space available. -->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp
         and extends the full height of the container. -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```